# React Native static images with variable path

Tags: image, react-native

Lets say i have **map()** loop inside my main component **render()** function.

```
<ScrollView>    
    {this.state.items.map((item, i) => {
       return(
        <MyItem key={i} item={item} />
       )
    })}
</ScrollView>
```

And the **render()** function of  component:

```
<View>
  <Text>{this.props.item.title}</Text>
  <Image source={require('../relative_path_to_image/' + this.props.item.imageName + '.png')}
</View>
```

If i do it this way i get an error: ***'Make sure the module exists...blah blah'***

If i do it the following way **i get the same error**:

```
render(){
  var imageSource= require('../relative_path_to_image/' + this.props.item.imageName + '.png');

  return (
   <View>
      <Text>{this.props.item.title}</Text>
      <Image source={imageSource}
    </View>
  )
}
```

And if i write it with **hardcoded** (see below) path **everything works fine**!

```
var imageSource= require('hardcoded_path_to_image.png');
```

So, i probably need a way to render images inside a loop with the require() function. I think it's a fair need to all apps, why is not working as expected?

Comment: Are you a 100% sure your relative path is correct? Can't you use absolute path on your loop?

Comment: Yes it's correct for sure, and i don't know outside the loop what image name might be on each item

Answer (score 1):

you cannot require a dynamic path for an Image. The image path should be compeletey static. I would suggest you pass the static path as the props to the component.

For example:

```js
class BlaBlaBla extends Component {
  constructor () {
    this.state = {
      myPicsArray: [
        require('path/to/some/image'),
        require('path/to/someAnother/image'),
        require('path/to/someAnotherAnother/image')
      ]
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    <ScrollView>    
    {this.state.items.map((item, i) => {
       return(
        <MyItem key={i} item={item} />
       )
    })}
    </ScrollView>
  }
}
```